Google Classroom 400 "admin_policy_enforced" despite being trusted app
I am getting a 400 admin_policy_enforced error, with no other information,  when a student tries to login to my service via oauth2 with google. We are testing the service with 2 separate schools currently and I get the error with both. These schools have many other apps that have been granted 3rd party permissions so I suspect it's something I'm doing on my end.
We are trying to access the Google Classroom (GC) APIs through the OAuth
permissions of the students.
The scopes we are asking for access to are:
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses.readonly 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.me.readonly

The bottom 2 scopes are the ones causing the issues, the students can log in if I remove them.
We are using the googleapis package.
On our sever we generate the OAuth Client:
const oauth2StudentClient = new google.auth.OAuth2({     
    clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,     
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,     
    redirectUri: ${process.env.ORIGIN}/api/oauth/google 
})

And generate our link with:
const googleStudentAuthUrl = oauth2StudentClient.generateAuthUrl({     
    access_type: 'offline',     
    prompt: 'select_account',     
    scope: studentScope //This is the 4 scopes mentioned above
})

We have successfully accessed the GC APIs through using the Admin's OAuth
access token in conjunction with domain-wide access / scopes. However we feel
that is more permissions than we need and it would be better to do this
through permissions granted to us by the student.
We encounter a 400 error " admin_policy_enforced " in our attempt to try the
Third Party trusted app route. Here is what we've tried so far:
We have been marked as a trusted 3rd party app for the relevant
Organizational Unit (OU)
For this they had a custom level of permissions we tried initially,
as well as the default 'trusted'
We have been granted permissions to access GC
To the best of my knowledge they have checked to make sure that the
scopes are not restricted or blocked
We were marked 'exempt' from blocked restrictions as well.
I am unable to figure how to further diagnose the problem or what I am missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Does the same thing happen when you add only https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses.readonly?

Yes, any of the classroom apis caused this issue.
